# How to vectorize triple nested loops?

Tags: r, nested-loops

I've done searching similar problems and I have a vague idea about what should I do: to vectorize everything or use `apply()` family. But I'm a beginner on R programming and both of the above methods are quite confusing.

Here is my source code:

```
x<-rlnorm(100,0,1.6)
j=0
k=0
i=0
h=0
lambda<-rep(0,200)
sum1<-rep(0,200)
constjk=0
wj=0
wk=0
for (h in 1:200)
{
   lambda[h]=2+h/12.5
   N=ceiling(lambda[h]*max(x))
   for (j in 0:N)
   {
      wj=(sum(x<=(j+1)/lambda[h])-sum(x<=j/lambda[h]))/100
      for (k in 0:N)
      {
         constjk=dbinom(k, j + k, 0.5)
         wk=(sum(x<=(k+1)/lambda[h])-sum(x<=k/lambda[h]))/100
         sum1[h]=sum1[h]+(lambda[h]/2)*constjk*wk*wj
      }
   }
}
```

Let me explain a bit. I want to collect 200 sum1 values (that's the first loop), and for every sum1 value, it is the summation of `(lambda[h]/2)*constjk*wk*wj`, thus the other two loops. Most tedious is that N changes with h, so I have no idea how to vectorize the j-loop and the k-loop. But of course I can vectorize the h-loop with `lambda<-seq()` and `N<-ceiling()`, and that's the best I can do. Is there a way to further simplify the code?

Comment: It's the first one, basically I want to calculate the difference between two edfs, thus the /100.

Comment: lambda and N values can be calculated outside the loop using vector commands.  That's about it here.  With the N and lambda values known you can probably accelerate wj calculation after that but not by much.  (wj could be two small `sapply`'s outside the loop just for the sum(x<=j) and then vectorized operations after that).  Perhaps a stronger answer will come along using `outer` for constjk and wk calculations.

Comment: In general, follow this rule: if your j-th calculation depends on the outcome of the (j-1) calculation, then you can't vectorize.  If it doesn't, you can.

Answer (score 5):

Your code can be perfectly verctorized with 3 nested `sapply` calls. It might be a bit hard to read for the untrained eye, but the essence of it is that instead of adding one value at a time to `sum1[h]` we calculate all the terms produced by the innermost loop in one go and sum them up.

Although this vectorized solution is faster than your tripple `for` loop, the improvement is not dramatical. If you plan to use it many times I suggest you implement it in C or Fortran (with regular `for` loops), which improves the speed *a lot*. Beware though that it has high time complexity and will scale badly with increased values of `lambda`, ultimatelly reaching a point when it is not possible to compute within reasonable time regardless of the implementation.

```
lambda <- 2 + 1:200/12.5
sum1 <- sapply(lambda, function(l){
    N <- ceiling(l*max(x))
    sum(sapply(0:N, function(j){
        wj <- (sum(x <= (j+1)/l) - sum(x <= j/l))/100
        sum(sapply(0:N, function(k){
            constjk <- dbinom(k, j + k, 0.5)
            wk <- (sum(x <= (k+1)/l) - sum(x <= k/l))/100
            l/2*constjk*wk*wj
        }))
    }))
})
```

Btw, you don't need to predefine variables like `h`, `j`, `k`, `wj` and `wk`. Especially since not when vectorizing, as assignments to them inside the functions fed to `sapply` will create overlayered local variables with the same name (*i.e.* ignoring the ones you predefied).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps greatly as now I can slowly transform all of the rest of the codes into sapply().

Answer (score 2):

Let`s wrap your simulation in a function and time it:

```
sim1 <- function(num=20){
  set.seed(42)
  x<-rlnorm(100,0,1.6)
  j=0
  k=0
  i=0
  h=0
  lambda<-rep(0,num)
  sum1<-rep(0,num)
  constjk=0
  wj=0
  wk=0

  for (h in 1:num)
  {
    lambda[h]=2+h/12.5
    N=ceiling(lambda[h]*max(x))
    for (j in 0:N)
    {
      wj=(sum(x<=(j+1)/lambda[h])-sum(x<=j/lambda[h]))/100
      for (k in 0:N)
      {
        set.seed(42)
        constjk=dbinom(k, j + k, 0.5)
        wk=(sum(x<=(k+1)/lambda[h])-sum(x<=k/lambda[h]))/100
        sum1[h]=sum1[h]+(lambda[h]/2)*constjk*wk*wj
      }
    }
  }

  sum1
}

system.time(res1 <- sim1())
#   user  system elapsed 
#    5.4     0.0     5.4
```

Now let's make it faster:

```
sim2 <- function(num=20){
  set.seed(42) #to make it reproducible
  x <- rlnorm(100,0,1.6)

  h <- 1:num
  sum1 <- numeric(num)
  lambda <- 2+1:num/12.5
  N <- ceiling(lambda*max(x))

  #functions for wj and wk
  wjfun <- function(x,j,lambda,h){
    (sum(x<=(j+1)/lambda[h])-sum(x<=j/lambda[h]))/100
  }
  wkfun <- function(x,k,lambda,h){
    (sum(x<=(k+1)/lambda[h])-sum(x<=k/lambda[h]))/100
  }

  #function to calculate values of sum1
  fun1 <- function(N,h,x,lambda) {
    sum1 <- 0
    set.seed(42) #to make it reproducible
    #calculate constants using outer
    const <- outer(0:N[h],0:N[h],FUN=function(j,k) dbinom(k, j + k, 0.5))
    wk <- numeric(N[h]+1)
    #loop only once to calculate wk
    for (k in 0:N[h]){
      wk[k+1] <- (sum(x<=(k+1)/lambda[h])-sum(x<=k/lambda[h]))/100 
    }

    for (j in 0:N[h])
    {
      wj <- (sum(x<=(j+1)/lambda[h])-sum(x<=j/lambda[h]))/100
      for (k in 0:N[h])
      {
        sum1 <- sum1+(lambda[h]/2)*const[j+1,k+1]*wk[k+1]*wj
      }
    }
    sum1
  }

  for (h in 1:num)
  {
    sum1[h] <- fun1(N,h,x,lambda)
  }  
  sum1
}

system.time(res2 <- sim2())
#user  system elapsed 
#1.25    0.00    1.25 

all.equal(res1,res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Timings for @Backlin`s code (with 20 interations) for comparison:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   3.30    0.00    3.29
```

If this is still too slow and you cannot or don't want to use another language, there is also the possibility of parallelization. As far as I see the outer loop is embarrassingly parallel. There are some nice and easy packages for parallelization.

Comment: If you have the time to try a C++ implementation

Comment: ... and if you are sufficiently fluent in C++.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's already fast enough (actually I found that it runs much faster on the computers in the lab than on my laptop, a good sign as I do not need to change much code now).